# Found result of index of /images in search engine

Tags: php, mysql, seo, search-engine

I am puzzle here, I never see this. I did some search on this without any success. I find a website on a search engine using Google. I typed something like awebsite.com and among the search result I got "index of /images" links to awesite.com/images/ which will list every images contained in that directory.

How to avoid this problem? As having the images available publicly just like that means the exposure of copyright images. Please help me to explain why is this happened and also how to avoid it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you (or the website awebsite.com) doesn't have an index page. Create an index.html or index.php page, upload it to the /www or /public_html directory and the user won't see the directory tree.

Comment: I am sorry but the index.php page is there.

Comment: What type of server? If this is on your own server, maybe you need to list index.php as one of the default documents that is accepted. I did this a long time ago on IIS when installing PHP on my local machine.

Comment: Linux I believe,this is not my server. The awebsite.com result is returned at first row as awebsite.com which definitely point to index.php and the second row is the "index of /images"

Comment: by the way, when I mouse over the result, first is awebsite.com while the second one is www.awebsite.com/images